# DNN Search Results Permissions

Tags: permissions, full-text-search, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I've made a custom DNN 7.2 module which is simply an entry form (with permissions on the page for some roles), and i use razor host scripts to retrieve its entries and display them in frontend for public users, and I've implemented ModuleSearchBase to integrate with DNN search, and i can see my entries in the index (using Luke to open the index)

The problem is that I can only view the results if and only if I'm logged in as a user with permission to use my backend module (entry form module), How could i make the results available to all users even anonymous ones ?

Comment: Add the module to a page with public permissions

Comment: @tatigo Unfortunately this can't be done, as it's an administration module, so it has to be with limited permissions (for admins only)

I've noticed that when i add search items there's a property "Permissions" which is string, Could it be useful in my situation ?  How can I use it ? Also there are properties "TabID, ModuleID" Unfortunately there's no documentation for each property !
Thanks in advance

Comment: the thing is if the page that the module is on has the visibility set to admins only your module permissions would be overwritten.

Comment: Have a look at our LuceneSearch module (http://ariciels.codeplex.com). You could write your own indexing provider and manage permissions as you want. It also include a template to display the results details if you need it because your detail module isn't accessible to anonymous users.

Comment: @tatigo I've made the page public and restricted access from my module code and now the problem solved, Also found the permissions property expects role name . But now have another problem with language cookie, when the language cookie is set to any language except en-US the i get no results, although the culture is set in the URL to a different value, don't know why this happens ?!!

Comment: There is a certain way to do localization in DNN. How do you set the different language? Since it's a different question, post another question with more details.

Comment: @tatigo check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086746/dnn-search-only-works-when-language-cookie-is-en-us