# DNN Search only works when language cookie is en-US

Tags: search, cookies, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I've a DNN 7.2 site with 3 languages and search functionality .
The search works only and only if the language cookie is set to en-US .

If the culture in the search service URL is fr-FR and the language cookie contains "fr-fr", which is very normal, the search will not work, if i changed the cookie manually to be "en-US" and left the url culture as is "fr-fr" the search works as expected and return french results .

Why this happens ? Is there a fix ?

Answer (score 0):

DNN7.2 Search is Locale-Aware, meaning content is indexed and found based on language/culture. 
The fr-fr page can only be found when search is executed from a French/French page, at the same time, culture-neutral pages can be found from any language. So if your portal has only one installed language (en-US), you will not see any of the multilingual options of the module.

The main points to check:

1. Language pack installed
2. Content Localization enabled
3. Add/Enable individual languages (you can do this from the Admin/Languages page as SuperUser)

Comment: Content localization is already enabled, and search results have locale value set, and the above scenario happens